# Issue with C# reading table on SQL Anywhere DB

Tags: c#, sqlanywhere

```
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PullData
{

class Program
{

static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    OleDbConnection connLocal = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SAOLEDB.10;Data Source=dental;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dba;PWD=sql;Location=1.2.3.4");

    OleDbCommand cmdLocal = new OleDbCommand("SELECT tran_num, amount, tran_date FROM transactions", connLocal);

    try
    {
        connLocal.Open();
    }catch (Exception connerr) { Debug.WriteLine(connerr.Message);}

    OleDbDataReader readLocal = cmdLocal.ExecuteReader();

    while (readLocal.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(readLocal.GetString(0), readLocal.GetString(1), readLocal.GetString(2));
    }
    readLocal.Close();
    connLocal.Close();

    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Above is the code I am attempting to run in Visual Studio 2015, I'm trying to connect to an old SQL Anywhere 10 DB, the connection string is directly from VS2015's Database Explorer that is connected and viewing tables (with the exception of my adding the `PWD`). This is just a stepping stone to view the table contents so I can later have the query written to a CSV or text.

The error I'm receiving when attempting to debug/run is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Which points to:

```
Console.WriteLine(readLocal.GetString(0), readLocal.GetString(1), readLocal.GetString(2));
```

Seems like it's not recognizing the reader. Anyone have any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the mislabeled title, it was auto-filled from a previous draft.

Comment: The error is because of `GetString`. This assumes that the column type is string convertible, which they are not.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, sorry I'm new to C# (programming in general) so missing a lot of derp situations. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Changed my values over to `readLocal.GetValue(0).ToString()` to get my results to work. Thanks again for the help, now to just get it to export to a file.

Comment: Partly unrelated, but why not use sql anywhere's own .net provider assembly?